# MySQL query to limit maximums and minimums

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
    INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `x`, `y`) VALUES (1, 0, 10), (2, 6, 10),
    (3, 9, 10), (4, 2, 9), (5, 4, 9), (6, 3, 8), (7, 7, 8), (8, 9, 8),
    (9, 0, 7), (10, 2, 7), (11, 5, 7), (12, 10, 7), (13, 2, 6), (14, 7, 6),
    (15, 0, 5), (16, 4, 5), (17, 9, 5), (18, 1, 4), (19, 3, 4), (20, 5, 4),
    (21, 10, 4), (22, 8, 3), (23, 3, 2), (24, 6, 2), (25, 2, 1), (26, 8, 1),
    (27, 0, 0), (28, 5, 0), (29, 6, 0), (30, 10, 0);
```

and it represent the following picture:

[image]

The numbers in the red or pink cells represent the "id" and the coordinates for those cells are "x" and "y".

All I have to do is to come up with a query to show all the cells (only the red ones), excluding the 10 cell within the gray square.

So far I have this:

```
    SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE
    x between 0 and 10 and
    x not between 2 and 8 and
    y between 0 and 10 and
    y not between 2 and 7
    order by id ASC
    LIMIT 30
```

Imagining that the grid goes bellow 0 and beyond 10 in both directions (not showing in the picture); the query must have way too many limits. Anyways, the output is not what I want because it only give me the cells in the corners (the ones within the green areas): 1, 3, 8, 27 and 30

another approach will be to subtract this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE
    x between 2 and 8 and
    y between 2 and 7
    order by id ASC
    LIMIT 30
```

from this one:

```
    SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE
    x between 0 and 10 and
    y between 0 and 10
    order by id ASC
    LIMIT 30
```

...but once again; i am unable to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just needs to exclude `x[2:8],y[2,7]`.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` 
WHERE NOT(x between 2 and 8 AND y between 2 and 7);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot; you save my life! I knew it was something really simple!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add the other "side" limits; the final query was implemented like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
`test_table` WHERE
x between 0 and 10 and 
y between 0 and 10 and
not
(x between 2 and 8 and
y between 2 and 7)
```